# Nixing [mixing]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[mixing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mixing) has 207 questions, no followers, and no tag wiki. There may be a legitimate music-related tag buried somewhere in there, but currently this is not the case.

The first five questions are about

- Mixing values in a database
- Mixing colors
- Mixing up variables
- Mixing audio tracks (but not in a musical sense, I believe)
- Shuffling a vector

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
No.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

In the sense that I might want to create an array by grabbing values from two others, maybe?

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No

Comment: And there [was one](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41468128/3) seemingly about mixed-language compilation.

Comment: No pun? It isn't featured yet!

Comment: So, it's time to start un[mixing] all those categories?

Comment: @CaptJak How about "Nixing Mixing"?

Comment: @code11 Beautiful.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of: "This one just isn't [mixing]"